# How to run multiple working threads on a linked linked list without blocking?

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, mutex, worker

I have a big linked list (about 200000 elements), and I have 6 working threads doing some calculations on this list.
I'm using mutexes to avoid race conditions, but instead of having a working thread to sleep while a mutex lock is released, is it possible to do something like

```
   if(other worker is on this node)
     go to next node
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not divide the list into 6 smaller lists beforehand, and give one smaller-list to each of the 6 threads?  Then at the end you can concatenate them back into a single larger list again, if you want to.

Comment: This is a classic producer/consumer model. There is lots of reference material on the web about it.

Comment: In c++11 there is an Atomic operations library to be used for lock-free operations http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic.

Comment: @EvgenyS. This question is tagged with C not C++. I suggest you propose a C solution.

Comment: @2501: C11 `_Atomic`s to the rescue!

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks for the idea. But each worker make a different task. Also, the operations of each worker are commutative.

Comment: If you use `pthread_mutex_trylock` it will fail without blocking so you can advance to the next node.

Comment: @EOF Well of course, I'm just explaining to a new user how SO works.

Comment: If you are skipping nodes and each of the threads does something different, it might easily be that you end up in a situation that adds more administrative overhead through trying to keep up with the nodes that were skipped by each thread  occupied by another node (I guess those would need to be revisited) than you actually gain. If the actions are really purely commutative, it might well be that you don't need any synchronization at all.

Comment: @2501 Thank you, I mixed up the tags. For C it is [Atomic operations library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) and read about lock-free programming in general.

Comment: If you aren't modifying the list itself (i.e. adding/removing/reordering nodes in the list), and each worker is touching different data from what the other workers read/write, then the list is effectively read-only and in that case you don't need to do any synchronization.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments!
I wish I could mark one as an answer. The thing is, I'm modeling a complex system where some 'random delays' (or time-delay interference) is needed to occur.
The linked-list is not static, and after all six threads have finished their work, the system will iterate a thousand times.